# One of four displays frezees

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, xrandr

I've got four displays connected to PC in such way:

`DVI-D-1 | HDMI-1 | HDMI3 | DP-1
1050    | 1680   | 1680  | 1050
0       | 1050   | 2730  | 4410`

My *xrandr* result is placed here: https://pastebin.com/DXSLHGGc

*DVI-D-1*, *HDMI-1*, *DP-1* is connected to NVIDIA card and HDMI3 is connected to Intel processor.

When I place anything on the third display, which is connected directly to motherboard via Display Port, **it freezes**. Others displays, connected to Nvidia card, works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure, but I believe that integrated (mobo/cpu) graphics is automatically disabled if you use external GPU.

Thus, if you have no GPU plugged in, you can use motherboard ports (assuming you have integrated graphics). And if you plug in a GPU, you should use its ports instead, but not both at once!

Comment: I think you may be wrong. http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86/319.12/README/randr14.html
These four displays work, but one of them (connected to Intel graphics), freezes.

Comment: @Victor you said that it was the monitor plugged with Display port (so the DP-1) which froze; and this one is plugged on your nvidia card, not on the Intel graphic (HDMI3)

Comment: @Victor wait a second. You firstly said your DP is connected to GPU, and then you said your DP is connected to mobo. I'm confused...

Comment: That's right. I am sorry. So the _HDMI3_ display which is connected to motherboard via Display Port (I am not responsible for assigning this names for displays...) freezes. Three displays connected to GPU via HDMI, DP, DVI works great.

Comment: What do you mean by freezes? Does it even show anything after booting up?